# displaying date time on xaxis in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have date field type POSIXct (2012-02-01 01:00:00). when I try to graph date and CPU, on the xaxis I get Mon, Tues, Wed etc. what I need to do so that xaxis actually displays the date and time. this is the data belong to server1 data frame:

```
Hostname Date                CPU 
server1 2012-01-29 01:00:00 23.79
server1 2012-01-29 02:00:00 23.91
server1 2012-01-29 03:00:00 25.65 
server2 2012-01-29 04:00:00 26.30 
server3 2012-01-29 05:00:00 24.33 
server3 2012-01-29 06:00:00 24.40
```

Comment: There a loads of similar questions already answered here. Please try the search function at the top, using `[r]` to search within the tag and otherwise suitable terms: `[r] date x-axis` would be my first try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
plot(df$Date,df$CPU, xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(side=1, at=df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```